# Oracle SQL - getting id using SUM and MAX

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a bit of difficulty when using SUM and MAX in oracle.

What I am trying to do is find the patient with the highest SUM of scores.

I would like to SELECT both the total score as well as the patient id.

If I run this query I get the highest score but not any of the patient details as expected.

```
        SELECT MAX(SUM(PM.score)) AS Total
        FROM Patient P, PatientMetabolic PM
        WHERE P.patientID = PM.patientID
        GROUP BY P.patientID
```

If I add patient ID like this

```
        SELECT MAX(SUM(PM.score)) AS Total, P.patientId
        FROM Patient P, PatientMetabolic PM
        WHERE P.patientID = PM.patientID
        GROUP BY P.patientID
```

I get a *not a single-group group function* error.

Any help would greatly be appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: Why do you have MAX(SUM(PM.score)). Simple MAX(PM.score) will give you the highest score.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't explain the problem very well. The PatientMetabolic table has 3 columns. PatientID, functionNo and score. So each patient has many metabolic functions and a score for each one (out of 5). MAX(PM.score) would only give highest value of any one function score.. Hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
WITH sums AS    
(
    SELECT P.patientID, SUM(PM.score) AS Total
    FROM Patient P, PatientMetabolic PM
    WHERE P.patientID = PM.patientID
    GROUP BY P.patientID
)
SELECT * FROM sums WHERE total=(SELECT MAX(total) FROM sums);
```

This gives you all patient IDs with MAX sum of scores.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RANK() OVER()` to rank the patients by score, and just pick the ones that rank highest;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT p.patientid, p.name, SUM(pm.score) AS Total,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(pm.score) DESC) rank
  FROM patient p
  JOIN patientmetabolic pm
    ON p.patientid = pm.patientid
  GROUP BY p.patientid, p.name
) 
SELECT patientid, name FROM cte WHERE rank=1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b141d/2).

If you don't want ties to return multiple results, you can instead use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` which will break ties.

If you want the entire list of rankings, just remove the rank condition on the outer query (in that case you may want to order by rank instead)